# PnP.Framewrok in an Windows App

Tags: pnp, pnp-js-core

Should it be possible to add PnP. Framework to Windows App? When I addd the nuget package I get following?

Unable to resolve dependency 'PnP.Core'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this error when trying to add the PnP.Framework package as well.

I ran:

```
Install-Package PnP.Framework -Version 1.2.0
```

and got:

```
Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'PnP.Core'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.
```

I took a peek at [the package on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PnP.Framework/).  I expanded "Dependencies," then clicked on "PnP.Core," which brought me to [the page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PnP.Core/) for the package it was complaining about.

In Visual Studio, I opened up the Package Manager Console, and put in the command to install it manually (listed on the package's page):

```
Install-Package PnP.Core -Version 0.5.38-beta2
```

"PnP.Core" was successfully installed.

Then I tried to run my first command:

```
Install-Package PnP.Framework -Version 1.2.0
```

This time it worked.  I'm not well versed in the dependency references of NuGet packages so I really couldn't say why it wasn't able to automatically add it, but this worked.